# Pyglet hello world example only shows randomly generated dashes of lines

Tags: python, pyglet

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()
label = pyglet.text.Label('Hello, world',
                          font_name = 'Times New Roman',
                          font_size = 36,
                          x = window.width // 2, y = window.height // 2,
                          anchor_x = 'center', anchor_y = 'center')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    label.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

This code was from the pyglet tutorial at https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/quickstart.html. When I run it, it doesn't draw the label but instead shows some weirdly generated strands of lines and dots:

[image: Output of the code]

I've tried with different texts and also tried to remove the font declaration, but it always results in something similar in the picture. I use Windows 10. Any clue as of why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your graphics driver up to date? Did you try to update pyglet (`pip install pyglet --upgrade`)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 My graphics driver is up to date. I also updated pyglet according to your suggestion but the problem still exist.

Comment: I see. Anyway, the issue is related to your system. In general the code works fine.